# How to combine a date and string in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to combine a date with a string in Postgresql.

```
CASE WHEN

multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'ANESTART' THEN
TO_CHAR(multi_app_documentation.nsma1_dt, 'YYYYMMDD') || multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans

END AS "ANESTART"
```

I need to concatenate these two. I have to change multi_app_documentation.nsma1_dt to YYYYMMDD format and then add the multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans (string) onto it. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Your code as written should work given appropriate data type for the column values. It would be easy enough to test in stand alone query: `select TO_CHAR(multi_app_documentation.nsma1_dt, 'YYYYMMDD') || multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans`.

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT(TO_CHAR(multi_app_documentation.dt, 'YYYYMMDD') || multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans)

Comment: The `CONCAT` is redundant to the concat operator `||`. All you need is: `select to_char('12/01/2021'::date, 'YYYYMMDD') || '_test';  20211201_test`.